# How can I force Chromium to never open a new tab?

Tags: mouse, raspberry-pi, chromium, fullscreen

I'm configuring a kiosk with a Raspberry PI and [FullPageOS](https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS) which must use a mouse with a wheel (for now). The OS works as expected and the page opens in full screen with no way to use other Chromium functions. However, if I middle click a link, a new window with the regular Chromium window opens, letting the user to surf the internet or use whatever it wants to.

Is there a configuration in Chromium or the OS to disable middle click (but keep the mouse wheel)?

Comment: like this thing? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk-extension/hbpkaaahpgfafhefiacnndahmanhjagi

Comment: or this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-new-tabs/kmpejnbkdndlkkoikcnocipmiaehcnac

Comment: @Gantendo Unfortunately those didn't work but they inspired me to get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this by doing the following:

- Install the [Disable keyboard shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-keyboard-shortcut/aidbmcboeighgdnilpdljbedbbiocphj) extension in order to disable keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> (new window), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> (new private window), etc.
- Install x11-xserver-utils in the OS and, based in this [answer from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/55988), set the following mapping to disable the middle click button.

  `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`

EDIT: You may also want to run this command at startup. In order to do that, set it in the *./scripts/run_onepageos* file before the `while`.

Thanks @Gantendo for driving me into the Chrome Web Store.